# Laravel , how to get loggedin user from jwt token of a custom table

Tags: php, laravel, api, jwt

I have created an authentication  with JWT in custom table. Authentication works fine, i am able to login and token is generated with success. The problem is not being able to get the information like 'id' etc FROM the generated TOKEN of the custom table.

```
    $token = $request->header('Authorization');
    $user = JWTAuth::toUser($token);
    return $user;
```

Returned information are form the '*user*' table not from the custom table  used for the jwt authenticaiton.
My configration looks like

```
    'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],

    'partners_credentials' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'table' => 'partners_credentials',
        'model' => App\Models\PartnerCredentials::class,
    ],
],
```

Guards

```
    'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'partners_credentials' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'partners_credentials',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
],
```

What i am missing here

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
$user = JWTAuth::user();
```

Comment: Could you please explain you answer. Surely doesn't work